# Functions as a argument

Tags: python

Just started learning python and came across this

```
def f(g):
    return g(2)

def square(x):
    return x ** 2

print(f(square)) # which gives 4
```

How does inputting square into the `f` function equate to `4`?

Comment: So what exactly is your goal here?

Comment: To understand replace `g` with `square` so, `f(square)` returns `square(2)`

Comment: Functions are objects too. Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881604/when-should-i-use-function-currying-in-python

Comment: functions are also objects, and when you use return values, their values are stored in the function obj.

Comment: Because `f` does `g(2)` with that argument, and `square(2)` gives you `2 ** 2` which is 4

Answer (score 3):

When you call a function, the value of the argument is assigned to the named parameter. The call

```
print(f(square))
```

can be thought of as "expanding" to

```
g = square
print(g(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `f(square)` is `square(2)` which is 2**2 so 4

Answer (score 0):

In python functions are first-class values, considered objects as anything else, hence you can pass them as parameters to another function.

In your case, you are "composing" `f` with `g`, which in turn has an invocation with fixed `2` inside f. In this sense, f is a function whose purpose is to feed 2 into another function, given as argument.

Knowing that `g` squares a number, it's easy to see how `g(2)` is 4, then f(g) will return 4.