# How to use kwargs in scipy.optimize.curve_fit() to pass a parameter that isn't being fitted

Tags: python, scipy, keyword-argument, scipy-optimize

The problem originates from fitting a diffraction pattern to data, where the number of slits is known beforehand. I have given a simplified version below that highlights the same issue. The function should fit the values of a and b in the data while passing n to the function. I could use a global n which would solve my issues, however, I would like to do this using **kwargs as shown in the scipy.optimize.curve_fit() reference.

Here is an example of the issue. The code generates the curve of 4sin(2x)+3cos(2x) with some noise as the data:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def curve(x,a,b,**kwargs):
    n = kwargs["n"]
    return a*np.sin(n*x)+b*np.cos(n*x)

x = np.linspace(-5,5,1000)
y = np.random.normal(loc=curve(x, 4, 3, n=2), scale=0.2, size=None)
result = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(curve, x, y, n = 2)
y2 = curve(x, *result[0], n=2)

plt.plot(x, y2)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

This returns the error

```
  File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Documents\Uni\lab year 2\diffraction\kwargs.py", line 13, in <module>
    result = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(curve, x, y, n = 2)

  File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minpack_py.py", line 834, in curve_fit
    res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)

TypeError: leastsq() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n'
```

Comment: Have you tried `args=(....,)`?  Many `scipy` functions use `args` to pass extra values to the function.  `least_squares` documents this; `curve_fit` doesn't, but talks about passing the task on to `least_squares`.  Or you might have to use `least_squares` directly.  The source of `curve_fit` appears to explicitly disallow `args`.

Comment: I tried args as you mentioned as this is used in other scipy methods such as fmin. However it returns the error: ValueError: 'args' is not a supported keyword argument.

Comment: Yes, I saw that test in the `curve_fit` code; that's why I suggested `least_squares` instead.

Comment: Its true that might work. I managed to get a couple other methods to work like using a lambda function or defining a class. However I was just wondering is there was a way to pass a variable directly into curvefit since it is annoying me that I can't figure it out. There must be a way to do it as it is a reasonably common thing to do and it is even defined in the method reference page. I use the curvefit method a lot in labs and figuring out how to use additional optional parameters would lead to a much more eloquent solution. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with `curve_fit` not accepting the `args` argument and after following the suggestion
[here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881604/when-should-i-use-function-currying), managed to get something working with a curried function

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def curve_curry(n):
    def curve(x, a, b):
        return a * np.sin(n * x) + b * np.cos(n * x)
    
    return curve

n = 2
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 1000)
y = np.random.normal(loc=curve_curry(n)(x, 4, 3), scale=0.2, size=None)
result = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(curve_curry(n=2), x, y)
y2 = curve_curry(n)(x, *result[0])

plt.plot(x, y, '.', color='lightgrey')
plt.plot(x, y2)
plt.show()
```

In my case, I had fit parameters `[p0, p1, p2]`, constants `c1, c2, c3`  and pre-defined functions `f1, f2`.  My code looked something like this:

```
def func_curry(c1, c2, c3, f1, f2):
    def func(x, *p):
        
        yinv = f1(c1) + x * c2 * (c3 + p[1] + p[2] * x ) / p[0]
        y = f2(yinv)
        
        return y
    
    return func 


# Curve fit using scipy

args = (c1, c2, c3, f1, f2)
p0 = [p0, p1, p2]
popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func_curry(*args), xdata, ydata, p0=p0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using `lmfit` for this (main author here). Your example would look like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import Model

def curve(x, a, b, n=2):
    return a*np.sin(n*x)+b*np.cos(n*x)

x = np.linspace(-5,5,1000)
y = np.random.normal(loc=curve(x, 4, 3, n=2), scale=0.2, size=None)

# turn your curve function into an lmfit Model:
model = Model(curve)

# create parameters for the fit, giving decent initial values
# note that n will use the default function value by default
params = model.make_params(a=3.2, b=2.5)

# fix n so that it is not varied in the fit:
params['n'].vary = False

# do the fit
result = model.fit(y, params, x=x)

# print out fit report
print(result.fit_report())

# plot data and best fit
plt.plot(x, y, label='data')
plt.plot(x, result.best_fit, label='fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

which will print a report of

```
[[Model]]
    Model(curve)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 7
    # data points      = 1000
    # variables        = 2
    chi-square         = 39.7903631
    reduced chi-square = 0.03987010
    Akaike info crit   = -3220.13053
    Bayesian info crit = -3210.31502
    R-squared          = 0.99678449
[[Variables]]
    a:  4.00080256 +/- 0.00914251 (0.23%) (init = 3.2)
    b:  3.00787199 +/- 0.00873116 (0.29%) (init = 2.5)
    n:  2 (fixed)
```

and a plot of

[image]