# Assessing correlation between variables in non-linear regression using scipy.OptimizeResult

Tags: python, correlation, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am using `scipy.minimize` for non-linear regression to estimate the vector `x` by minimising the function

[image]

where `a, b, c` are constants and we have `n` pairs of `(t, y)` observations.  Below are some test results:

```
x0 = [2000.0, 0.0, 0.1]
res = scipy.optimize.minimize(my_func, x0)
print(res.x, res.fun)
[ 2.00016543e+03 -5.95934615e+00  8.52615660e-02] 1.8537556040946759

x0 = [4000.0, 0.0, 0.1]
res = scipy.optimize.minimize(my_func, x0)
print(res.x, res.fun)
[ 4.00001292e+03 -3.96950262e+00  1.70509802e-01] 1.8537556026712332
```

As the above output shows, the residual error is the same in both cases.  I think this means that the first and second variable are correlated.  Is it possible to estimate the degree of correlation from the `OptimizeResult` object that `scipy.minimize` returns?

In principle, it should be possible to do this using the `optimize.curve_fit` function but this does not accept the `args` keyword (eg. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75879324/how-to-use-kwargs-in-scipy-optimize-curve-fit-to-pass-a-parameter-that-isnt-b)), which I am using the pass in the values of `a, b, c`

Comment: What does your function look like? All this seems to be saying is that the minima of the function occur at the same `y` value, similar to how all the minima of `sin(x)` occur at y = -1. As for the correlation, they're related because they're both minima of the same function.

Comment: Hi @Jared.  I have added the equation to be minimised.  I take your point about the `sin(x)` example but I am not getting the same minima - I (think) I am getting values that are correlated